# Looking for a little help to make a basic Zenity script that feeds its users' input into a variable in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspberry-pi4, zenity

I've written a simple script with user input to assign latency values to a pair of interfaces (on an RPi / Raspbian device) to emulate latency.

```
#!/bin/bash

# be sure to update the interface names on lines 6, 7, 14, 15, and 17 to match host interface names

echo "Removing existing induced latency values"
sudo tc qdisc del dev enp5s0 root netem
sudo tc qdisc del dev enp0s31f6 root netem
echo "..."
echo "Existing induced latency values removed"

echo -n "Enter new per-interface induced latency value in ms (example: '35' for 35ms per interface): "
read latencyms

sudo tc qdisc add dev enp5s0 root netem delay ${latencyms}ms
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp0s31f6 root netem delay ${latencyms}ms

echo "Changed induced latency value on enp5s0 and enp0s31f6 to ${latencyms}ms"
```

I'd like to make it a bit more user-friendly with a GUI that does essentially the same thing as the command line, and I'm hoping to use something simple like Zenity.

I've entered the basics into a Zenity script, but I'm not sure how to have that user input from the Zenity GUI become the variable $latencyms in the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

latencyms=$(zenity --entry --title="Please enter the new latency value per-interface")
if [ -n "$latencyms ]
then
        zenity --info --text="Latency has been changed to $latencyms per-interface" --no-wrap
fi
```

Basically what I want to happen is the user input opens the bash script, runs the processes, and feeds the user input to the variable $latencyms. Is this as simple as I'm hoping it will be?

Comment: "Snippets" are only for HTML, Javascript and CSS. Use the `{}` button to code-format other content.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're storing your data in `LATENCY` when you say you want it stored in `latencycms`? (In general, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system; script-defined names should contain at least one lower-case character -- this is per POSIX conventions given at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the code formatting! I've updated the post.

On your second question, it's because I'm pretty much a hack. Updated the variable in the zenity script to all lower case.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your second example should give you a clue that there's some syntax missing there (an unclosed quote). If you fix that, what's the difference between the actual behavior you get and the behavior you intend?

Comment: ...btw, `bash -x yourscript` is always helpful to see what values are actually in use at runtime; you should get a log message like `+ latencyms=...something...` when you run your script that way. What's the something you get? Is it the value (entered in the GUI) that you expect?

Comment: The zenity script runs perfectly - popup asking for $latencyms input, outputs that value to the return message stating that latency has changed, which is great. Now I just need to figure out how to have that script run my command-line script that adds the latency to the two interfaces (based on user input from the zenity pop-up). Can that be done within the same zenity script, or does the zenity script have to call the latency script?

Again, I apologize if this is super-basic stuff - trying to figure out a quick-and-dirty way to make it so execs can adjust this parameter on the fly.